# Is there a good and fast way to dry used flies before storing them?

Tags: fishing, fly-fishing, fishing-tackle

I have been spending many hours by the water recently and usually try a lot of flies before I find what is working on a particular day. The question is: what to do with all the flies that got wet after I used them? I reckon that I should dry them, but is there any nice way to do it before putting them back into my fly box?

Edit: attaching them to hats seems to be a popular option, but what if I don't want to damage my hat or if I don't wear one?

Comment: Attach them to your [hat](http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/fishing-hat-fly-rod-reel-bass-flies-24544723.jpg)?

Comment: That would help if I wore a hat and wanted to damage it :)

Comment: wearing a hat will help cut down glare and enable you to see into the water more easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of [dry fly floatant powder](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002138YZM) is quite effective at drying off smaller flies. I believe it's the same silica gel that is used to keep packaged electronics dry.

But I typically just press flies between folds of a cotton t-shirt briefly. This will draw most of the water out and restore "floatability" to the fly. It should also leave it dry enough to put back into storage.

Comment: Yes all of these dry shake/desiccant products are very effective at drying flies of a variety of sizes. I usually apply a gel such as gink to help it repel water after that.